# Wordpress H1 TAG Homepage

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with tag H1 on my website. In all sub pages, i have hidden tag H1 to SEO, i don't know why but always this tag is this same like a option from menu, but if i will update menu label, the tag has not change. I would like to change tag H1 on home page to have a more score at SEO. In source code of website i found this line:

```
<h1 class="sc_layouts_title_caption">Home</h1>
```

Do you have any idea how to change this tag on home page?

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more and that the class name includes 'title', I'd say this is related to the Page Title. To fix you need to edit the home page in the admin page editor and edit the title section.

Comment: title selection is correct one, but the Home is not been changed ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Does the page title for home say 'Home'? Are you maybe using an SEO plugin that is setting the title?

Comment: If im create new page always tag will been correct, but if im setup this web page as HOME PAGE, automaticlly h1 tag will been changed to HOME...

Comment: Does the <title> tag include 'Home'?

Answer (score -1):

I changed "Home" in one of the WordPress plugins (ThemeREX Addons) with Loco Translate. That worked!

Comment: How this is related to tag change?

Comment: The plugin (ThemeREX Addons), in my case, locks the tag to "Home". Changing it with Loco Translate makes it more SEO friendly. H1 is the most important header on every page.